# Why Ajax request fired after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to send Ajax request once changes anything in any form fields, but in below code Ajax request fired after page load also.

```
window.submitting = false;
$('form#AddForm').submit(function() {
    window.submitting = true;
});

var timeoutId;
var saveHandler = function() {
    console.log('Change');

    if (window.submitting)
        return false;

    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        // Runs 1 second (1000 ms)
        autoSave();
    }, 1000);
};

$('form input, form textarea, form select').bind('input propertychange change', saveHandler);

function autoSave() {
    // unbind events
    $('form input, form textarea, form select').unbind('input propertychange change');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $('form#AddForm').serialize() + '&autosave=true',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            // Let them know we are saving
            console.log('Saving........');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('done');
            // bind events back
            $('form input, form textarea, form select').bind('input propertychange change', saveHandler);
        },
        error: function(){
        //alert('error');
            // bind events back even if reqeust fail
            $('form input, form textarea, form select').bind('input propertychange change', saveHandler);
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: i think you have to put the ajax on submit button's click not globally

Comment: @RamSingh i am using auto save functionality in my code.

Comment: how frequent you are repeating the ajax?

Comment: @vikas I have put this into a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/s1so829m/) and it appears to be working as desired. What version of jQuery are you using; What browser are you noticing the issue with; and what other scripts are on the page?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon yes right i also checked not fired Ajax request on Page load. Using jQuery Version jquery-2.1.0.min.js